# sml configuration on ubuntu, how to run sml on command instead of the full path?

Tags: shell, unix, sml

I followed this instruction 
http://smlnj.cs.uchicago.edu/dist/working/110.70/NOTES/INSTALL

and install smlnj on mu laptop(ubuntu).

However, when I want run run the sml
I have to change to /usr/share/smlnj/bin/ 
and run ./sml

before I can use sml.

I read something before, that I can add it to my PATH? 
so that I can run ./sml without going to that directory?

Comment: `PATH=/usr/share/smlnj/bin:${PATH}; export PATH`

Answer (score 3):

Well, either add `/usr/share/smlnj/bin` to your PATH env variable, or make a symlink to the command in a standard folder like `/usr/bin`, or write a small wrapper script which would also allow you to  make additional adjustments like working directory, further environment variables and the like...